# How to prevent this repeated assignment in an else if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The following function validates the fields of a form:

```
validateFields () {
  let invalidFields = []
  utils.eachDeep(this.schema, field => {
    if (!field.validation) return // don't validate
    else if (field.validation.isRequired && !field.value) {
      field.errorMessage = 'Required field error'
      invalidFields.push(field)
    } else if (field.validation.minLength && field.value.length < field.validation.minLength) {
      field.errorMessage = 'Minimum length error'
      invalidFields.push(field)
    } else {
      // no errors
      field.errorMessage = ''
    }
  })

  invalidFields.length > 0
    ? this.isFormValid = false
    : this.isFormValid = true
}
```

As you can see I'm repeating `invalidFields.push(field)` in every `else if` statement. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I don't think you can give that the error messages are different. Is there anything common or parent to the two else ifs?

Comment: You don't even need `invalidFields` if you can `return false` upon the first encounter of an invalid field and use something like `every()` to iterate.

Comment: @le_m I need a way to check whether the form is invalid after ALL the fields have been validated.

Comment: if you want to capture all the invalid fields and return multiple error messages then you are doing it right else you can just set a boolean variable valid with default true which is updated to false if any invalid field is encountered and return the function.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma could you give me a sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to remove the push() within the else if block, you could do it this way:

```
validateFields () {
  let invalidFields = []
  utils.eachDeep(this.schema, field => {
    field.errorMessage = '';

    if (!field.validation) return // don't validate
    else if (field.validation.isRequired && !field.value) {
      field.errorMessage = 'Required field error'
    } else if (field.validation.minLength && field.value.length < field.validation.minLength) {
      field.errorMessage = 'Minimum length error'
    }
    if(field.errorMessage){
      invalidFields.push(field)
    }
  })

  invalidFields.length > 0
    ? this.isFormValid = false
    : this.isFormValid = true
}
```

Comment: Genius! (Or maybe I'm too dumb.)